# Maximum code size for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it 10MB for all files, or 10MB / file, 150MB in total? I'm using Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like these have been updated.

Current file limit is 10k
Max size of application file: 32M

Full limits:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#Quotas_and_Limits 
and 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#Quotas_and_Limits

Comment: Links are outdated. Are there different limitations between the python and java runtimes?

Comment: I don't have permission to update this answer, but I added another one below with the new limits.

Comment: This is the old limit and is no longer accurate.

Answer (score 7):

You can upload up to 3,000 files and each code or static files can have up to 10 megabytes, but the total size of the whole application can't exceed 150 megabytes.

The summary is [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Quotas_and_Limits):

- maximum total number of files (app files and static files): 3,000
- maximum size of an application file: 10 megabytes
- maximum size of a static file: 10 megabytes
- maximum total size of all application and static files: 150 megabytes

Answer (score 5):

This appears to have been updated. New limits from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Code are:

> - Code & Static Data Storage - First 1 GB:   Free
> - Code & Static Data Storage - Exceeding 1 GB:   $ 0.026 per GB per month
>
> No single static data file may be larger than 32MB.
>
> The storage quota applies to the total amount of code and static data
>   stored by all versions of your app. The total stored size of code and
>   static files is listed in the Main Dashboard table. Individual sizes
>   are displayed on the Versions and Backends screens respectively. Free
>   apps may only upload up to 1 GB of code and static data. Paid apps may
>   upload more, but will be charged $ 0.026 per GB per month for any code
>   and static data storage that exceeds 1 GB.